# Possible threading problem in SI4T

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, si4t

Is anyone aware of a threading issues within SI4T?

We have a custom Elasticsearch indexer plugged into SI4T that uses JEST to check and create necessary Elasticsearch indexes based on the publication id (e.g. publication_10) passed in to the commit method and then index documents into these indexes. The code is based pretty much on the SOLR example that comes with with SI4T, apart from the Elasticsearch/JEST parts.

Our blueprint is a traditional diamond (content/templates) and has a master website publication for pages that several child publications inherit from.

We've noticed that when we publish pages via the static components that are used on them, from the master (with the include in Child Publications option) we can see a load of transactions in the queue - all as expected apart from we end up with pages from different publications indexed into the wrong index - so index "publication_36" has a document with id "tcm:51-xxxx-64".

I don't quite understand storage extensions or the effect of a multi-threaded Deployer - but it seems like because parts of SI4T are singleton, the multi-threaded Deployer is altering the publication id value passed in to the SI4T storage classes.

**UPDATE**

cd_storage:

```
<Storage 
    Type="persistence" Id="si4tdb" dialect="MSSQL" 
    Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.JPASearchDAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="...." />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="..." />
        <Property Name="password" Value="..." />                        
    </DataSource>
    <Indexer 
        Class="org.si4t.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIndexer" 
        Url="http://localhost:9200" 
        Clustername="http"
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt" 
        Mapping=" ..."/>
</Storage>


<Storage Type="filesystem" 
        Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" 
        Id="301FileSystem" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">                  
    <Root Path="D:\Live\Redirects" />
    <Indexer 
        Class="org.si4t.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIndexer" 
        Clustername="http" 
        Url="http://localhost:9200"
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt,txt" 
        Mapping="..."/>
</Storage>

<Storage Type="filesystem" 
        Class="com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory" 
        Id="si4tFile" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="false">               
    <Root Path="D:\Live\Binaries" />
    <Indexer 
        Class="org.si4t.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIndexer" 
        Clustername="http" 
        Url="http://localhost:9200"
        DocExtensions="pdf,docx,doc,xls,xlsx,pptx,ppt" 
        Mapping="..."/>
</Storage>
```

[ELasticsearch indexer can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/neilgibbons/7fbef358f6578e7a893d)
The approach was to use the publication id passed to the commit method to form the index name - check if it exists (create if not) - and then index documents using this index name.

[Example log file can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/neilgibbons/b2e8dba0c37a253e98a1)
I can see on line 1116 for exmaple, where several pages across publications have all gone into index "publication_36".

```
pool-1-thread-6 2015-03-06 16:25:42,072 DEBUG ElasticsearchIndexer - {"took":483,"errors":false,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:52-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}},{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:51-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}},{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:49-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}},{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:47-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}},{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:40-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}},{"index":{"_index":"publication_36","_type":"Pages","_id":"tcm:36-1786-64","_version":1,"status":201}}]}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of threading issues in SI4T, but you seem to have quite a complex setup. Figuring this out, would mean for me to know your storage configuration, access to example transaction packages and logging. Could you provide those? Everything the deployer does (and SI4T) happens on the transaction Id and never the publication id in the sense of changing that publication Id. It may be that one transaction has pages from multiple publications, but the standard deployer should take that into account. If not-then it's a definite CD bug or a bug in the way the index>pub mapping happens in SI4T

Comment: There are definitely no transactions with items from multiple publications. I just denied an ER asking for that ;)

Comment: Good, I wouldn't expect that. :) Then I suspect it's the way index urls are mapped to publication Ids, but I can't say much about it without knowing the setup.

Comment: @Raimond - I'll update my answer with the info you're looking for. But its a good start to know each individual transaction only holds a single publications items. 
But the SearchIndexProcessor is a singleton - the Deployer is multi-threaded - is it possible different threads could call the triggerIndexing method therefore causing a commit cross-transactions?

Comment: That's not possible in theory, but may be a bug if it is. Even though it is a singleton, I've built in guarantees that only one thread takes one transaction. Having said that, if you have to DAOFactories in use in the same transaction, you might need a bugfix I did a while back. But, even then it can never be that a transaction puts stuff in the wrong publication id because of the multi threadedness. I suspect it's rather the config parts which have an issue.

Comment: "The config parts"? I chose to calculate index name in code rather than the Solr way of using config - could that be a root cause?

Comment: That might be. Do you use multiple DAOFactories for multiple item types as well ?

Comment: Raimond, updated the storage conf example above (I removed the long Mapping string for brevity its only used when creating the index). This is a DD4T solution, so we use one JPASearchDAOFactory for pages and DCPs, one FSSearchDAOFactory for TXT files (we wanted this file stored in a specific place) and one FSSearchDAOFactory for binaries.

Comment: Ok. Keep in mind I'm releasing a new version soon, which solves an issue with having multiple DAOFactory types. The current version won't break anything, but a bit more robust implementation will be in place. If you need this fast, check the code here: https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/tree/feature/bugfixing/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t

Comment: @Neil - did you ever share this? Got someone interested in a similar solution

Comment: No - I'm not sure I can as it was part of clients solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suspicion is the the problem lies in ElasticSearchIndexer. Consider the following code:

```
private String publicationId = null;
private String indexname = null;
//.. truncated

public void commit(String publicationId) throws IndexingException 
{

    System.out.println("Commit: "+ publicationId);
    log.debug("ElasticsearchIndexer - commit called: " + publicationId);

    this.publicationId = publicationId;
    this.indexname = "publication_" + this.publicationId;
```

The DAO factories **can call one commit for multiple transactions**. This means that say you publish out a page with the option "Also publish in Child Publications" on, then you will have multiple transactions across various publications, in one commit.

Secondly, the way the Indexer works, is by building a stack of items to add, remove or update. What this means is that, you can have items from different publications on for instance the `itemAdds` stack, which will get indexed in the same index, because you use the this.indexname property for all items on that stack.

**Solution**

Construct the index name for each individual items for each commit* method, like so:

```
log.info("Adding pages and component presentations");

for (Map.Entry<String, SearchIndexData> entry : itemAdds.entrySet())
{
    SearchIndexData data = entry.getValue();

    String id = data.getUniqueIndexId();

    // NEW
    String publicationId = data.getPublicationItemId();
    String currentIndexName = "publication_" + publicationId;

    // Truncated

    builder.addAction(new Index.Builder(source).index(currentIndexName).type(this.INDEX_TYPE).id(id).build());
}
```

This will ensure each item is going into its proper index.

**What is the use of the class variable this.indexname?**

The mechanism to send the publication Id with the call to *commit* is actually meant to be able to configure cd_storage_conf.xml to have a separate index URL / name per publication Id. Since this is not configured in your cd_storage_conf.xml, you get behaviour like this. However, for your case I recommend to fix this in code as described above.

Comment: Many thanks Raimond. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Raimond - I've made the changes you suggested and this has resolved the issue. Many thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Great stuff! Be sure to share this indexer with the SI4T project! ;)